# How can I format a list of files with directory names in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, find, format, report

I have a find command that I am using in a script to list archived files for a given week, starting every Saturday. The script works great, but there is some formatting I would like if possible.

The files listed are archived files, but I don't need the directory name "archive" in my list(as shown under script output).

For the variable I'm using in the find command, I used the function: date +"%b %d" -d "last saturday". This gets me the last saturday just as it states.

Any help or tips would be great.

```
--USES DAYOFWEEK variable TO GET THE LAST SATURDAY; THEN GETS      
--FILES WITH A MODIFED DATE FOR THAT SATURDAY OR NEWER  

find . -newermt "$DAYOFWEEK"  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TI:%TM %f\n"
```

script output

```
2016-02-01  10:10  dir_name1
2016-02-01  10:10  archive
2016-02-01  07:58  file1.txt
2016-02-01  07:58  file2.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file3.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file4.txt
2016-02-01  10:10  dir_name2
2016-02-01  10:10  archive
2016-02-01  07:58  file12.txt
2016-02-01  07:58  file22.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file32.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file42.txt
```

I would like it to be formatted like this(in alphabetical order by client name, then oldest file to newest):

```
dir_name1
2016-02-01  07:58  file1.txt
2016-02-01  07:58  file2.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file3.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file4.txt

dir_name2

2016-02-01  07:58  file12.txt
2016-02-01  07:58  file22.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file32.txt
2016-02-02  07:58  file42.txt
```

Comment: well for starters we could use the %y, then we need to display characters after the ' d ' string, I have the following:
find . -newerat "20:00"  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TI:%TM %y %f\n" | cut -d'd' -f2     which would work if the files/dirs do not contain the d character :). I'm getting no where with awk on this one so far

Comment: what about a script that runs on the results of the comand, something like$(find.....)? we could use conditionals on the results to accomplish the required resukts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after can't be done in just one command, I don't think

I don't have the time to try and recreate a directory structure that matches yours and populate it with files, but think this approach *should* work for you ...

```
find . -newermt "$DAYOFWEEK" -type f  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TI:%TM %h %f\n"| sort -t' ' -k3,3 -k1,2  |  awk 'BEGIN{old=""} {if ($3 != old){print "";print $3;print $1" "$4}else{print $1" "$4};old=$3}'
```

Comment: That looks great. I may see if I can tweak this a bit. Thanks